# tableViewCell segue does not work. because of trigger?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I needed to add, into a working swift project, a tableViewCell, and a segue from it. I did, but it did not call the `prepare` function.
so I compared the existing segues in the storyboard xml with my new segue, and I did find a difference, my segue has `trigger` property.

I guess I now need to remove this segue and add a new one.

so, How do I create a segue without `trigger="accessoryAction"` property?

existing:

```
  <connections>
    <segue destination="x1H..." kind="show" identifier="segueToSettingA" id="e4m..."/>
  </connections>
```

my new non working:

```
  <connections>
    <segue destination="Zg7..." kind="show" identifier="segueToSettingB" trigger="accessoryAction" id="7eW..."/>
  </connections>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `"accessoryAction"` trigger. According with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44618823/3241041), there is a bug with `accessorybuttontappedforrowwith` and `UITableViewCell` segue.

You can try changing to `trigger="selection"` or removing the trigger, but the best solution is to use the visual interface and mark the option:

[image]